# Numba mergesort

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have written a mergesort in Python/Numba:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def merge( x ):

    n = x.shape[0]
    width=1

    r   = x.copy()
    tgt = np.empty_like( r )
    while width<n:
        i=0
        while i<n:
            istart = i
            imid = i+width
            iend = imid+width
            # i has become i+2*width
            i = iend

            if imid>n:
                imid = n

            if iend>n:
                iend=n
            _merge( r, tgt, istart, imid, iend)

        # Swap them round, so that the partially sorted tgt becomes the result,
        # and the result becomes a new target buffer
        r, tgt = tgt, r
        width*=2

    return r

@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def _merge( src_arr, tgt_arr, istart, imid, iend ):
    """ The merge part of the merge sort """
    i0   = istart
    i1   = imid
    for ipos in range( istart, iend ):
        if ( i0<imid ) and ( ( i1==iend ) or ( src_arr[ i0 ] < src_arr[ i1 ] ) ):
            tgt_arr[ ipos ] = src_arr[ i0 ]
            i0+=1
        else:
            tgt_arr[ ipos ] = src_arr[ i1 ]
            i1+=1
```

I have written a test for it:

```
def test_merge_multi(self):

    n0 = 21
    n1 = 100

    for n in range( n0, n1 ):
        x = np.random.random_integers( 0, n, size=n )

        with Timer( 'nb' ) as t0:
            r = sas.merge( x )
        with Timer( 'np' ) as t1:
            e = np.sort( x, kind='merge' )
        #print( 'r:%s'%str(r))
        #print( 'e:%s'%str(e))
        print( 'nb/np performance %s'%(t0.interval/t1.interval ))
        np.testing.assert_equal( e, r )
```

I used this `Timer` class:

```
import time

class Timer:    

    def __init__(self,title=None):
        self.title=title

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.title:
            print( 'Beginning {0}'.format( self.title ) )
        self.start = time.clock()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.clock()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start
        if self.title:
            print( '{1} took {0:0.4f} seconds'.format( self.interval, self.title ) )
        else:
            pass#
            #print( 'Timer took {0:0.4f} seconds'.format( self.interval ) )
```

The test results are:

> ```
> nb/np performance 9307.846153856719
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
> nb/np performance 0.7142857142925115
> nb/np performance 0.8333333333302494
> nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
> nb/np performance 0.9999999999777955
> nb/np performance 0.8333333333456692
> nb/np performance 0.8333333333302494
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 0.8333333333456692
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 0.8333333333456692
> nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0000000000185036
> nb/np performance 1.2000000000044408
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0000000000185036
> nb/np performance 1.2000000000088817
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 0.9999999999814962
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666512469
> nb/np performance 1.0
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333024937
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428435483
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333209976
> nb/np performance 1.1666666666728345
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333209976
> nb/np performance 1.000000000012336
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333209976
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
> nb/np performance 1.3333333333456692
> nb/np performance 1.499999999990748
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857074884
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428616743
> nb/np performance 1.1428571428435483
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
> nb/np performance 1.1249999999895917
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857233488
> nb/np performance 1.4285714285623656
> nb/np performance 1.249999999993061
> nb/np performance 1.1250000000034694
> nb/np performance 1.2857142857029569
> ```

Graphed results (from a different run):

[image]

Graphed results from a longer run:

[image]

[Please note that for n<=20, numpy uses an insertion sort when the mergesort is called](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c.src).

So you can see that for small values of n, the numba version of the mergesort beats the numpy version.

However, as n gets larger, numpy then consistently outperforms numba by a factor of 2.

Why is this? And how could I optimise the numba version to beat the numpy version for all n?

Answer (score 1):

- **Stability**

  The single most important feature of merge sort is stability: elements comparing equal retain their original order. As coded `merge` loses stability: shall `src_arr[i0]` and `src_arr[i1]` compared equal, `src_arr[i1]` is copied first. A standard remedy is to compare them backwards; in pseudocode:

  ```
  if (src_arr[i1] < src_arr[i0])
      copy src_arr[i1]
  else
      copy src_arr[i0]
  ```

  You may also check that `numpy` code at your link does exactly that.
- **Performance**

  Fallback to insertion sort for small subarrays is important. The code is simpler and allows better optimization, particularly in reusing registers, which is very hard to achieve with recursive calls. It will be also interesting to inspect the generated code.